# Webbrowser Click Button With No ID Or Name

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use the WebBrowser in Visual Studio 2012 (Visual Basic) to click a button. I have done a lot of research, but all I can find is to click with an ID or a name.

Here is the HTML code.

```html
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-default" style='float:right'>
    Login<i class="gicon-chevron-right"></i>
```

I am going to have the webbrowser hidden, & then when the user clicks Button1, it invokes the click on the webbrowser. Please help.

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far? Show how you have built the browser and what have try to click on the button.

Answer (score 2):

You need to search for your element one by one. Try something like this:

```
For Each elem As HtmlElement In wb1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    ' Check the attributtes you want
    If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "btn btn-default" Then
        'Check even the text if you want
        If elem.InnerText = "Login" Then
            'Invoke your event
            elem.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    End If
Next
```

This will search on all the `button` elements on the document. You could narrow the searching by looking inside some element that contains your button that has ID or something:

```
Dim myElem As HtmlElement = wb1.Document.GetElementById("myContainerId")
For Each elem As HtmlElement In myElem.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    '...
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

simple code :

```
WebBrowser1.Document.Forms(0).InvokeMember("submit")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim HtmlElementcoll As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        For Each elem As HtmlElement In HtmlElementcoll
            ' Check the attributtes you want
            If elem.GetAttribute("value") = "Sign In" Then
                'Check even the text if you want
                '  If elem.InnerText = "Sign In" Then
                'Invoke your event
                elem.InvokeMember("click")
                'End If
            End If
        Next
```

i have modified the code above and its working add HtmlElementCollection  and you are good to go..