# Clicking specific Co-Ordinates of a site using GetElementFromPoint

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to automate a click process using vb.net and logging into a specific site.

My current issue is that the input fields and login button do not have id's nor a class and because I can't find a working way of modifying their values or invoking a click I'm taking the brute route of using co-ordinates and invoking a click on the co-ordinates.

```
    Dim NewPoint As New Point(71, 386)
    Dim ele As HtmlElement = Form2.WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(NewPoint)
    ele.InvokeMember("click")
```

I have gotten those specific co-ordinates using a timer and a calculation to calculate the true x and y of the site

```
    lbl_mousex.Text = "Mouse Position X:" & MousePosition.X - Form2.WebBrowser1.Location.X - 8
    lbl_mousey.Text = "Mouse Position y:" & MousePosition.Y - Form2.WebBrowser1.Location.Y - 29
```

But even after this it's not invoking the click at all.

I'm slowly running out of ideas and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

See [Webbrowser Click Button With No ID Or Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18483473/3453226).

```
For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
    ' You can check name, type or whatever you want
    If Element.GetAttribute("name") = "submit" Then
        Element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It doesn't have a class nor does it have any inner text. I'm trying to edit the code to how I would need it but to no avail.

The HTML is so

    `<input type="image" name="submit" src="view/imagesSite/login.gif">`

Comment: It appears to be a site specific problem as I've used that on another site and it worked fine. However the site I originally want to use this on does not do anything with that code.

Also I fixed my problem by analysing the post data that is sent out when I click the login button of the form and it was in plain test so I could easily manipulate the string to login with.