# WebBrowser Click on [N, N] location

Tags: vb.net, location, webbrowser-control

So i want to (with button) press given location on webbrowser (e.g: 16, 52)

I tried to explain as best as i could my question in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found very little success in attempting to click a given point. I've tried code like

`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementFromPoint(New Point(myX, myY)).InvokeMember("click")`

However the browser does not respond so far.

Take a look here: 
[Webbrowser Click Button With No ID Or Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480731/webbrowser-click-button-with-no-id-or-name/18483473#18483473)