# VB.NET GetElementByTagName Doesn't work

Tags: vb.net, dom, getelementbyid

i want to press a button in a website with the InvokeMember("click") code. Basically the websites html code is this one :

```
                   <em class='coins'>
                    <span class="click"></span>
```

And i tried using the answer found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480731/webbrowser-click-button-with-no-id-or-name) but it doesn't seem to work. Do you know why? Am i doing something wrong?I also used the

```
If elem.InnerText = "Login" Then
```

but it didn't seem to help either.
Here is the code in my Windows Form Application in Visual Studio :

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each elem As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span")

        If elem.GetAttribute("class") = "click" Then

                elem.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Sorry if this question counts as a duplicate, it is not the same as the other i made**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must use (className) and (.Equals() for two strings) like this code:-

```
    If elem.GetAttribute("className").Equals("free-coins-click") Then

            elem.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: omg man i love you, i have been learning programming for the past 3 days now more than 6 hours a day, just to find what i need and its 2 lines of code. you made me happy thank you very much!!!

Comment: i will pick it as a solution as soon as i can

Comment: The `.Equals()` call isn't _necessary_. This works just as well: `If elem.GetAttribute("className") = "free-coins-click" Then`. Note to @oToGaming for the future as well.

Comment: @VisualVincent, while `.Equals()` is not necessary, its usage (particularly its overloads) yields more readily predictable results than the VB string equality operator that is dependent on setting of `Option Compare` (see: [Comparing Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators#comparing-strings).  The VB equality operator also treats `Nothing` (null) as an empty string which can confuse people not familiar with the nuances of the language.

Comment: @TnTinMn : Yes _its overloads_ I can agree with are more "powerful", but in the case of checking a simple (non-null) string _using no overloads_ it doesn't make much of a difference unless `Option Compare` is set to `Text`.